# Stop uiwebview when close veiw controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I am loading sound cloud url in uiwebview and when I close the screen that contains the webview the sound is still working in background

can any one tell me how to stop it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewDidDissapear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDissapear(animated)

    webView.stopLoading()
}
```

---

**Edit**: as per comment this is working for OP

```
viewDidDissapear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDissapear(animated)

        webView.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil);
    }
```

Comment: try to load some request instead of stopLoading() in viewDidDissapear

Comment: I solved it by using : soundWebview.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSError *activationError = nil;
    BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: NO error: &activationError];
    if (!success) { /* handle the error in activationError */ }
}
```

Don't forget to import framework  in your appDelegate Class

Comment: Don't forget to import framework  <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> in your appDelegate Class